# Corda: Locate a transaction that consumed a StateRef

Tags: corda

In Corda, given a `StateRef` that is `CONSUMED`, how can I find the transaction that consumed it?

Comment: should I be using `TransactionGraphSearch`? This appears to be a trace-back on the transaction dependency list, which is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As of Corda 3, there is no API to provide the transaction that consumed a state.

With the expected introduction of SGX to prevent nodes from seeing transactions or portions of transactions that don't concern them, we are not looking to extend the `TransactionStorage` API at this time.