# If a StateRef is consumed how can I locate the Transaction that consumed it?

Tags: corda

Background:

This question has been asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63688600/searching-the-chain-can-i-find-if-something-has-been-consumed-and-what-it-was-co) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49366716/corda-locate-a-transaction-that-consumed-a-stateref).  Both replies state that there is no way to locate the Transaction that consumed a State with the current API.

Question:

Any application I am thinking about building on Corda would require users to examine the “lifecycle” of a state for audit/legal purposes.

Transactions are essential to piece together that audit trail. If this functionality has not been built into the API I am concerned that R3 is trying to tell me that users/CorDapps should **not** be allowed to search the Transactions in their vault.  For example I currently make heavy use of `CordaRPCOps.internalFindVerifiedTransaction()` which is deprecated.

Is there a specific reason that we can’t search Transactions with a rich set of tools like we search for States?  Am I overlooking some security concern?  How would I prove to a lawyer that I’ve transferred an asset if I can’t pull up the Transaction that shows what Party received the asset along with their signature?

Answer (score 1):

- In the first question that you referenced, Ashutosh provided a high-level solution but there was no follow up from the person that posted the question (not cool and unprofessional); the second question references Corda 3; we're now at Corda 4.6! This was ages ago.
- Just because `CordaRPSOps` doesn't have a certain API, doesn't mean you can't achieve your goal.
- You can write a flow that executes your requirement, then call that flow with your RPC proxy:

```java
List<SignedTransaction> auditTrail = proxy.startFlowDynamic(AuditTrailFlow.class,
                                                            linearId);
```

- Inside your flow you can do something like this:

```java
// Criteria to get CONSUMED and UNCONSUMED states.
QueryCriteria statusAllCriteria = new VaultQueryCriteria(Vault.StateStatus.ALL);

// Criteria to get a certain LinearState by its linearId.
LinearStateQueryCriteria linearStateCriteria = new LinearStateQueryCriteria()
        .withExternalId(Collections.singletonList(linearId));

// By default Corda returns the results in pages of 200 records, 
// you can modify that default size; and you must loop through the pages 
// to get all of the results.
Vault.Page<YourState> results = getServiceHub().getVaultService()
        .queryBy(YourState.class, statusAllCriteria.and(linearStateCriteria));

// This is a simplified version where I get the first record in the result set; 
// again, you must loop through all the pages if you have more than 200 records 
// (it's highly unlikely that your state was updated more than 200 times though).
SecureHash txHash = results.getStates().get(0).getRef().getTxhash();

// Now you have the transaction that created your state 
// (i.e. the transaction that consumed a previous version of your state
//  and created the new version of your state).
SignedTransaction tx = getServiceHub().getValidatedTransactions()
        .getTransaction(txHash);
```

- Now it's up to you to decide what your flow returns, it can for instance return a `List<SignedTransaction>` which contains all the transactions that form the audit trail of your state.

Comment: Adel the comments section is too small to reply so I just created an Answer below yours.  Really appreciate your insights.

Answer (score 0):

The method Adel has provided is actually why I created this question.  I was doing exactly what he outlines and stumbled onto the fact that it only works about ~75% of the time.  Let me elaborate…

Adel is correct – anytime you need functionality for your RPC client that hasn’t been provided through the API but is possible using the `ServiceHub` you can create a flow, annotate it with `@StartableByRPC` and perform the necessary steps that return a result.  Then simply call that flow from your RPC client.  I was highlighting the deprecation of `cordaRPCOps.internalFindVerifiedTransaction()` more as indicator that R3 is moving towards less ability to search Transactions from RPC versus more.

I’m still really new to Corda but generally my States follow a consistent “Lifecycle”.  This is especially true of tokens. Let’s discuss each stage and whether the method that I/Adel am using will work:

**Stage 1 - creation/issue**

This method will always work because the Transaction will produce an output State that you will be a Participant of so you will save it in your vault.  When you search for the `LinearID` this State will be found and you can cross-reference to the Transaction.

**Stage 2 – updating/moving**

This method *might* work depending on the nature of your CordApp and how you’ve written your flows.  For example the `MoveNonFungibleTokens()` flow in the `TokenSDK` moves something out of your vault to someone else’s vault.  You will not be a `Participant` in this new State so there will be no record of it in your vault.  When you search your vault for the `LinearID` it will not return any State that you can cross-reference to this Transaction.

I think this situation can be avoided if you build your flows differently.  For example by including a `StatesToRecord.ALL_VISIBLE` in the `FinalityFlow` you can force the storage of States that you are not a `Participant` of.  I haven’t gone through the code but I assume R3 chose not to do that with the `MoveNonFungibleTokens()` flow.

**Stage 3 – deletion/redeeming**

This method doesn’t work because there is no output State produced.  So when you search your vault for the `LinearID` it will not return any State that you can cross-reference to this Transaction.  The only way I have come up with to find these Transactions is to:

1. Acquire the `ConsumedTime` in the `StateMetaData` returned from a `QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria`
2. Use this time to query the `NODE_TRANSACTIONS` table by `TIMESTAMP` and grab the `TX_ID`
3. Examine the Inputs of each Transaction returned from that query and see if they contain the `LinearID` I am looking for

(If anyone has a better idea please let me know)

I hope I haven’t made some rookie mistake in my analysis/testing.  It would be great if Corda saved the consuming Transaction ID along with the other `MetaData`.  That would make it easy to locate transactions under all circumstances.

Adel I really appreciate the time you took to answer my question.  I am not going to mark it as solved because I am hoping you or someone else can show me that I have overlooked something.  If there isn’t a better way maybe someone from R3 will see this and consider it.

**Appendix**

Below I’ve included some logging I use to help analyze transactions.  It’s a nice visual way to see some of the examples I am talking about if you are just getting into Corda.  If it is confusing just ignore it.

Here is a Transaction where PartyA moves a NonFungibleToken to PartyB.  Note that the output state doesn't have PartyA listed as a `Participant` which means PartyA will not store this state.  So if you search for the `LinearID` nothing will be found:

```
   ______________________________________________________________________________________
    SignedTransaction Info from node: PartyA...  
   _____________________________________________________________________________________
    - getID: 8AD8CEE3340EE23BA1751C24D0652253A8ABB2EA19755704C6A8F42466B14A72 (SecureHash)

    - Notes: []

    - getNotary: O=Notary, L=London, C=GB (Party)

    - # of RequiredSigningKeys: 2 (Set<PublicKey>)
        PartyA with PublicKey: DL363eMqRKM8FegtiyEbF1F1zpq4nLp4paaTrKYbMjdKKg (Base58)
        Notary with PublicKey: DL47z5vzXwPzFeMnfHsPiWru7wpWi7c5QmthPw4P8az7Ay (Base58)

    - # of MissingSigners: 0 (Set<PublicKey>)
     
   ______________________________________________________________________________________
    WireTransaction Info from node: PartyA...        
   ______________________________________________________________________________________
        - getID: 8AD8CEE3340EE23BA1751C24D0652253A8ABB2EA19755704C6A8F42466B14A72 (SecureHash)
    
        - # of Commands: 1 (List<Command>)
                MoveTokenCommand
                    # of Signers: 1 List<PublicKey>
                        PartyA with PublicKey: DL363eMqRKM8FegtiyEbF1F1zpq4nLp4paaTrKYbMjdKKg (Base58)
    
        - # of Inputs: 1 (List<StateRef>)
            SecureHash: B4AD7096BDF29628E1D30907DCFF84E68C1AF8344F1781DE7D549B96D112A836 Index: 0
                TransactionState<NonFungibleToken>
                    getData <ContractState>: TokenType(tokenIdentifier='Ruby-3b1f1ccd-b175-48f1-af0f-e4d82015d31e', fractionDigits=0) issued by PartyA held by PartyA
                        Participants: PartyA with PublicKey: DL363eMqRKM8FegtiyEbF1F1zpq4nLp4paaTrKYbMjdKKg
                    getContract (String): com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.contracts.NonFungibleTokenContract
                    getNotary (Party): O=Notary, L=London, C=GB
                    getConstraint (AttachmentConstraint): Type - SignatureAttachmentConstraint,  PublicKey - DLGqTr8CsXnGGh9d8uve8NWhHsHNm5b6eKzUpNPGqeNVMH (Base58)
                    getEncumbrance (Int, max allowed = 1): null
    
        - # of Outputs: 1 (List<TransactionState<ContractState>>)
            Index 0: 
                TransactionState<NonFungibleToken>
                    getData <ContractState>: TokenType(tokenIdentifier='Ruby-3b1f1ccd-b175-48f1-af0f-e4d82015d31e', fractionDigits=0) issued by PartyA held by PartyB
                        Participants: PartyB with PublicKey: DL5nGmwTZ6jF6FrpNRZ4hbDAW48ut8DxjJ8YZTQw4xY339    !!! PartyA is not listed !!!
                    getContract (String): com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.contracts.NonFungibleTokenContract
                    getNotary (Party): O=Notary, L=London, C=GB
                    getConstraint (AttachmentConstraint): Type - SignatureAttachmentConstraint,  PublicKey - DLGqTr8CsXnGGh9d8uve8NWhHsHNm5b6eKzUpNPGqeNVMH (Base58)
                    getEncumbrance (Int, max allowed = 1): null
    
        - # of Attachments: 1 (List<SecureHash>)
            SecureHash: 34705DC9A2C8599998BBDBA7C3D13609AF04D8B3A772F7134D685ECC926D8320 (CordaRPC successfully located Attachment in storage)
    
        - getTimeWindow: null (TimeWindow)
```

Here is an example of removing a `LinearState` (redeeming a token looks the same).  Note that there is no Outputs so if you search for `LinearID` no state will be found making it impossible to cross-reference to this transaction:

```
     __________________________________________________________________________________
      SignedTransaction Info from node: PartyA...        
     __________________________________________________________________________________
        - getID: 4D09C6CBACD104821BEB3095E90C350FE4EA690FD7F8CEA24B71E847EEE10684 (SecureHash)
    
        - Notes: []
    
        - getNotary: O=Notary, L=London, C=GB (Party)
    
        - # of RequiredSigningKeys: 2 (Set<PublicKey>)
            PartyA with PublicKey: DL363eMqRKM8FegtiyEbF1F1zpq4nLp4paaTrKYbMjdKKg (Base58)
            Notary with PublicKey: DL47z5vzXwPzFeMnfHsPiWru7wpWi7c5QmthPw4P8az7Ay (Base58)
    
        - # of MissingSigners: 0 (Set<PublicKey>)
    
         
   ______________________________________________________________________________________
    WireTransaction Info from node: PartyA...        
   ______________________________________________________________________________________
        - getID: 4D09C6CBACD104821BEB3095E90C350FE4EA690FD7F8CEA24B71E847EEE10684 (SecureHash)
    
        - # of Commands: 1 (List<Command>)
                Delete
                    # of Signers: 1 List<PublicKey>
                        PartyA with PublicKey: DL363eMqRKM8FegtiyEbF1F1zpq4nLp4paaTrKYbMjdKKg (Base58)
    
        - # of Inputs: 1 (List<StateRef>)
            SecureHash: A45446E1764AB7055B348BC6AAB5E9332BCCFEF21E157A1B28360CC986CDD459 Index: 0
                TransactionState<MyLinearState>
                    getData <ContractState>: linearID: 73fac293-2c89-42fa-8572-7d31e0de567f ExternalID: LinearSate-123 administrator: O=PartyA, L=London, C=GB badPeople: []
                        Participants: PartyA with PublicKey: DL363eMqRKM8FegtiyEbF1F1zpq4nLp4paaTrKYbMjdKKg
                    getContract (String): com.template.contracts.MyLinearStateContract
                    getNotary (Party): O=Notary, L=London, C=GB
                    getConstraint (AttachmentConstraint): Type - SignatureAttachmentConstraint,  PublicKey - DLCTymWiNxvGWE117QUKSjeW71yaaGc5tNL2i8Zp8dFUvE (Base58)
                    getEncumbrance (Int, max allowed = 1): null
    
        - # of Outputs: 0 (List<TransactionState<ContractState>>)   !!! No Outputs !!!
    
        - # of Attachments: 1 (List<SecureHash>)
            SecureHash: DB05B1A5B285C73C3C48F81E8D07B8DDF51E7EE9852219D4D65EE934F9524527 (CordaRPC successfully located Attachment in storage)
    
        - getTimeWindow: 22-Oct-2020 15:24:40 to 22-Oct-2020 15:24:50 (TimeWindow)
```

Comment: When a responder flow calls `SignTransactionFlow`, that flow will implicitly call `ReceiveTransactionFlow` which will resolve all the transaction dependencies and verify them; meaning you'll get the entire graph and Corda will attest that what you received is correct. So if A created a state then it was moved to B then B moved to C then C moved it to D; when D calls `SignTransactionFlow` it will receive all the transactions that lead to creating the state it received (i.e. was moved to it).

Comment: By default `ReceiveTransactionFlow` won't store those received dependencies; you must do some changes (see [here](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/release/os/4.7/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/flows/ReceiveTransactionFlow.kt#L21-L22)). So I think you need to write a flow that calls `ReceiveTransactionFlow` and stores the entire transactions graph; then you can go back to my previous solution of looping through the evolution of the state and extracting the transactions that created that evolution, since your vault should have all that information.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to record what I settled on:

If I build my own Flows from scratch I can force the storage of all states with `StatesToRecord.ALL_VISIBLE` in the `FinalityFlow` and then use what Adel outlined to cross reference states to transactions.  This will cover Creation/Issue and Change/Move transactions.  It will not work for Delete/Redeem transactions because the lack of an output state.

If I am using pre-built flows like in the TokenSDK it is more difficult.  If the developers didn't add in a parameter to set the StatesToRecord there may be no solution.

The TokenSDK [documentation](https://github.com/corda/token-sdk/blob/master/docs/IWantTo.md#use-flows-from-token-sdk-issue-move-and-redeem-tokens) says that if someone is an Observer their recording strategy will be StatesToRecord.ALL_VISIBLE.  I did test this and it works unless you are the `Party` performing the move/issue.  It seems you get filtered out as an Observer.

To solve this I switched to using the inline version i.e. `MoveNonFungibleTokensFlow`/`MoveFungibleTokensHandler`.  While these flows don’t have a parameter for `StatesToRecord` I discovered that after I perform the move I could call a `FinalityFlow`/`ReceiveFinalityFlow` with `StatesToRecord.ALL_VISIBLE`...

Mover Node:

```
SignedTransaction signedTransactionMove = subFlow(new MoveNonFungibleTokensFlow(partyAndToken, participantSessions, observerSessions, queryCriteria));
return subFlow(new FinalityFlow(signedTransactionMove, participantSessions, StatesToRecord.ALL_VISIBLE));
```

Receiver Node:

```
subFlow(new MoveFungibleTokensHandler(otherSideSession));
subFlow(new ReceiveFinalityFlow(otherSideSession, null, StatesToRecord.ALL_VISIBLE));
```

I was really surprised this didn’t cause an error.  I thought the notary would complain but it doesn’t.  This ensures that the mover will save the moved state (normally they wouldn’t because they aren’t a `Participant`).  Then you can use the solution Adel outlined.

You can also do this for issuing (i.e. when you issue directly to another party you will not be a participant of that state and thus will not save the state)...

Issuer Node:

```
SignedTransaction signedTransactionIssueToken = subFlow(new IssueTokensFlow(nonFungibleToken, participantSessions, observerSessions));
return subFlow(new FinalityFlow(signedTransactionIssueToken, participantSessions, StatesToRecord.ALL_VISIBLE));
```

Receiver Node:

```
subFlow(new IssueTokensFlowHandler(otherSideSession));
subFlow(new ReceiveFinalityFlow(otherSideSession, null, StatesToRecord.ALL_VISIBLE));
```

I have no solution for “exiting” type Transactions that have no Output i.e. `RedeemNonFungibleTokens()` because there is no output state that could get saved with `StatesToRecord.ALL_VISIBLE`.  If you do not save the TransactionID outside of Corda at the time of transaction there is no way to locate that transaction with the API.

Ideally R3 would save the consuming Transaction ID in the `VAULT_STATES` table when it records the `CONSUMED_TIMESTAMP`.  Then it would be easily available in the metata of a vault query.  I’m considering putting this in as a request.